# React passing state Objects to child component

Tags: reactjs, javascript-objects

I am new to using React and have run into an issue with passing state.

I have a get request in my App.js which I am using to add and Object containing Objects to state. I am then trying to pass this data to a component to loop over the objects and display the data.

the problem is the data isn't getting picked up in the component, it just returns currencies [object object]. If I add everything directly to the Component, rather than passing state down, then everything works as expected.

Also in my component i've had to comment out this.createTable() as this causes the following  error:

```
×
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
// Get the keys of the first item.
> 60 | Object.keys(Object.values(data)[0]).forEach(key => {
     | ^  61 |   const header = document.createElement('th');
  62 |   header.textContent = key;
  63 |   headerRow.append(header);
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated!

**App**

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      currencies: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    axios.get('https://blockchain.info/ticker') 
      .then((response) => {

        const data = response.data; // Returns an Object containing multiple Objects

        this.setState({
          currencies: data,
          isLoaded: true
        });

      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

  } 

  render() {

    const currencies = this.state.currencies; 
    
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <div className="app__col">
          <CurrencyData currencies={currencies} />
        </div>
        <div className="app__col">
          <p>FORM</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
} 
export default App;
```

**Component**

```
class CurrencyData extends Component {


  componentDidMount() {

    const data = this.props.currencies;

    console.log(data);

    // this.createTable(data);


  } // END componentDidMount


  createTable = (data) => {

    const table = document.createElement('table');
    
    // Create headers.
    const headerRow = table.insertRow();
    
    // Empty cell for currency column.
    headerRow.insertCell();
    
    // Get the keys of the first item.
    Object.keys(Object.values(data)[0]).forEach(key => {
      const header = document.createElement('th');
      header.textContent = key;
      headerRow.append(header);
    });

    // Create rows of data.
    Object.entries(data).forEach(([ currency, values ]) => {
      const row = table.insertRow();
      const header = document.createElement('th');
      header.textContent = currency;
      row.append(header);

      Object.values(values).forEach(value => {
        row.insertCell().textContent = value;
      });
    });

    document.querySelector('#table').append(table);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="table"></div>
    )
  }
}

export default CurrencyData;
```

Comment: can you console.log data in createTable, and post here the output?

Comment: Object.keys expects an object, which means that Object.values(data)[0] doesn't return one, if you want help with that please post here console log of data

Comment: @Roy.B it just returns ```{}```

Comment: in here const currencies = this.state.currencies;  its also empty {} in every render?

Comment: my guess is that in the first render currencies is empty object and in second render currencies have data so you need to check if data is not empty object and then run  this.createTable(data)

Comment: @Roy.B in App.js it returns ```App.js:42 {USD: {…}, AUD: {…}, BRL: {…}, CAD: {…}, CHF: {…}, … ``` but in the component it errors ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'currencies' of null
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having an empty object as the default value for currencies

so here if an empty object is passed the above error would be thrown as its undefined

```
Object.keys(Object.values(data)[0]);
```

So you should have a check before doing this like `data!==null and data.length>0`

And you should set the default value of currencies to an empty array as you are setting an array to it.

Comment: Thanks for that, adding ```if (data!==null && data.length > 0)``` stops the error on the Object, but no data is being displayed in the table as it looks as though the the object is empty still. createTables isn't being populated by props.

Comment: do the same call on componenDidUpdate , as you have called it in the mount it wont be called when the props are updated so try the componentDIdUpdate

Comment: @moody1208 did you try it ?

Comment: No,not yet. I've added the conditional statement to App.js mentioned above which has allowed createTable to work.I'm going have keep having a play with it tho

Comment: only thing is if the service return an empty array it will show the loading even after you get the response

Comment: Ok i'll give it ago in ```componentdidmount()``` and see how the data is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Add this condition to your `App.js`, because when the currency component first time renders it receives an empty `{}` object, which leads to error. Check [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-ptolemy-7dyjh?file=/src/MyApp.js)

```
{Object.keys(this.state.currencies).length > 0 ? <CurrencyData currencies={this.state.currencies} /> : "loading"}
```

Comment: thanks for that. The condition has allowed for createTable to run! Only thing is it has stripped out the ```th``` data from ```  Object.keys(Object.values(data)[0]).forEach(key => {
      const header = document.createElement('th');
      header.textContent = key;
      headerRow.append(header);
    }); ```

Comment: Actually, fixed the ```th``` issue by removing ```if (data!==null && data.length > 0)``` from ```createTable()```